# ios show one fields in UIPickerView instead of all

Tags: ios, swift

I have a forms to fill in, inside the form, there are 6 fields is fill by select. I use textfield in the form and connect to pickerView as below. 
However, I only want each field selected one at a time instead of all pickerview options appear.

```
let pickerViewA = UIPickerView()
pickerViewA.dataSource = self
pickerViewA.delegate = self
textfieldA.inputView = pickerViewA

let pickerViewB = UIPickerView()
pickerViewB.dataSource = self
pickerViewB.delegate = self
textfieldB.inputView = pickerViewB
```

[image: Screenshot of result]

Do I have to use nestedClass  for UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource??

Comment: Could you clarify what your current implementation results in?

Comment: I added the screenshot result, u see there are number of fields in the form, they are not related, so only one pickview per fields should be display at a time

Comment: Could you show how you present the UIPickerView ?

Comment: Wow, you question helped. instead of component: I should have use the _pickerview .
numberOfComponents() return1 instead of return 6

thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can archive your result with `UITextField` delegate methods and `UIPickerView` delegate methods.

Here i explain with detail :

- You have to load your textfield relevant data to your pickerview while particular textfield is active.
- Suppose you have textfield for country selection so at that time you need to load country relevant data to your pickerview.
- Make sure you just need to add only 1 component into `numberOfComponents`